# Why does VLC audio/video playing get delayed/blurry?

Tags: video, vlc

Recently my VLC player started acting a bit weird. It gets delayed by a split second and even the image blurs too. I have decided to run it via the terminal and whenever this delay/blur happen, I get an error message. Can anyone tell me what the solution is to this delay?

Here is the error message:

```
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)
```

[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 389 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 397 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 504 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 596 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 614 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 689 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 729 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 804 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[h264 @ 0x7fafa8cc7300] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0x7fafa8cc7300] decode_slice_header error
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 828 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 907 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 402 ms)
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 426 ms)
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 522 ms)
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 609 ms)
[00007fafc80122f8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 352 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 386 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] Missing reference picture, default is 0
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd6f560] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cdb6ae0] Missing reference picture, default is 65534
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cdfe120] Missing reference picture, default is 65534
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] Missing reference picture, default is 65534
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cd16ba0] Missing reference picture, default is 65534
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cdfe120] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x7faf8cdfe120] Missing reference picture, default is 65540
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 476 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 479 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 574 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 610 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 692 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 714 ms)
[00007fafc8009c18] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007faf8ce4b888] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)

Comment: Does vlc play other video files OK ?   Does that same video file play OK on other players ?

Comment: @ScottStensland thanks for the reply. It seems to be a random thing. It doesnt seem to happen regularly.